# How to subtract from another table in SQL

Tags: sql

[image]

```
SELECT 
COUNT(ca.Plate) as 'OccupiedElectricSlots'
FROM cities C
JOIN ParkingHouses HS on C.Id = hs.CityId
JOIN ParkingSlots PS on HS.Id = ps.ParkingHouseId
LEFT JOIN Cars Ca on  PS.Id = Ca.ParkingSlotsId
WHERE ps.ElectricOutlet = 1
GROUP BY hs.HouseName, C.CityName

SELECT 
 MAX(Ps.SlotNumber) as 'ParkingSlotTotal'
,MAX(PS.SlotNumber) - Count(ca.Plate) as 'FreeSlots'
,SUM(CAST(PS.ElectricOutlet AS INT)) as 'ElectricOutlet'
,Hs.HouseName
,C.CityName
FROM Cities C
JOIN ParkingHouses HS on C.Id = hs.CityId
JOIN ParkingSlots PS on HS.Id = ps.ParkingHouseId
LEFT JOIN Cars Ca on  PS.Id = Ca.ParkingSlotsId
GROUP BY hs.HouseName, C.CityName
```

How can I subtract the first tables numbers on the second one?
I want to see how many free slots that have electric outlet.
Like this Column ElectricOutlet - OccupiedElectricSlots = result

I'm quite new at SQL, but I have tried to outer apply (don't fully understand it), and I tried to join them both tables togheter. Tried different where conditions but I'm stuck atm.

Comment: Does `OccupiedElectricSlots = 1` mean that slot 1 is occupied? or does it mean that 1 slot is occupied?   (Adding expected output to your question might solve this...)

Comment: On a side note: You are using wrong quotes, and this can cause problems in certain situations. Single quotes are for string literals. Use double quotes for names, e.g. `COUNT(ca.Plate) as "OccupiedElectricSlots"`. (Typically we don't use names that need quotation marks in SQL at all, as SQL is not the place where we finally show the data to some user. So, we'd use just `COUNT(ca.Plate) as occupied_electric_slots` for instance. This, too, can help avoid problems in paricular situations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your queries are almost identical as far as I can see. You can change your first query to:

```
SELECT COUNT(CASE WHEN ps.ElectricOutlet = 1 THEN ca.Plate END) as 'OccupiedElectricSlots'
FROM cities C
JOIN ParkingHouses HS on C.Id = hs.CityId
JOIN ParkingSlots PS on HS.Id = ps.ParkingHouseId
LEFT JOIN Cars Ca on  PS.Id = Ca.ParkingSlotsId
GROUP BY hs.HouseName, C.CityName
```

I.e., instead of filtering on ps.ElectricOutlet you just ignore those rows in COUNT. Now you can just:

```
SELECT 
[...]
,SUM(CAST(PS.ElectricOutlet AS INT)) - COUNT(CASE WHEN ...) AS result  
[...]
FROM Cities C
JOIN ParkingHouses HS 
    ON C.Id = hs.CityId
JOIN ParkingSlots PS 
    ON HS.Id = ps.ParkingHouseId
LEFT JOIN Cars Ca 
    ON PS.Id = Ca.ParkingSlotsId
GROUP BY hs.HouseName, C.CityName
```

Comment: That realy did the trick. Thank you so much. It makes so much sense.
Shall look more into CASE. Appreciated a lot!

Comment: @Daniel: If this answer solved your problem, please accept it by clicking the tick/check next to it.

Answer (score 0):

The MINUS operator is used to subtract the result set obtained by first SELECT query from the result set obtained by second SELECT query.
MINUS compares the data in two tables and returns only the rows of data using the specified columns that exist in the first table but not the second.

Comment: I don't think this is what he is looking for, I beleive he just wants to subtract numbers between the two queries